# How connect Playfab to a database different from Azure DB?

Tags: database, azure, database-connection, game-development, playfab

I am totally new to playfab and I got a question about how the data storage works.
I noticed that playfab allows you to explore the players' data using KQL in the data explorer, and that's ok.
I also noticed that the maximum retention period is 90 days.
I was wondering if [I can connect playfab to a database service other than azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/playfab/features/data/dataconnections/) to store all the data about my app.

In poor words, I'm trying to find a way to save permanently ALL of my data efficiently, and I was wondering if setting for example 999,999 days in retention would be enough or if I need to do something else, like paying for azure data storaging services

Thanks for the tip and have a good time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a data archival storage solution which can be integrated with PlayFab, then Azure Storage account is the best option.

You can create `Container` in Azure Blob Storage account and upload a blob in it (eg. bacpac file) and store it in `Archive access tier`. Refer image below.

[image]

> **Archive tier** - An offline tier optimized for storing data that is rarely accessed, and that has flexible latency requirements, on the
> order of hours. Data in the Archive tier should be stored for a
> minimum of 180 days.

You can later change the access tier to cool or hot to access the file based on requirement.

Refer: [Archive access tier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/access-tiers-overview#archive-access-tier), [Archive a blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/archive-blob?tabs=azure-portal)